# for loop passing variables to awk cmd

Tags: awk

I'm trying to make this loop work

```
for i in 5 10 15; do awk -v var=${i} '$2>var' file.txt > par${i}.pos; done
```

Where file.txt is a tab delim like in

```
A 2
B 4
EE 5
F2 7
FF 12
C 5
D 13
GAG 15
```

so that I can collect lines of file.txt that have `2nd col > 5` in `par5.pos` and so on, but it doesn't work.

As in `par5.pos`

```
F2 7
FF 12
D 13
GAG 15
```

or `par10.pos`

```
FF 12
D 13
GAG 15
```

Comment: `it doesn't work` is the worst possible problem description. Imagine taking your car to a mechanic and just telling them `it doesn't work` and expecting to get it fixed. See [ask].

Comment: Add `file.txt` to your question (no comment).

Comment: Dear Madza. From the description of your problem and the code you give, we cannot say what is wrong. The code looks correct as it is. Why the code is not working as you are expecting is hard for us to guess. Could you [edit] your question and add some more information about what you want to achieve and why you believe that this code is not working. Some example input and expected output would be a good start. Currently we can come up with various reasons why this does not work. Some are awk related (field separator) others are shell related (correct shell?) or even OS related (win lin osx).

Comment: No worries, just added the file. Yeah, interesting that it might be actually correct. I'll continue to investigate on my side too. Thxs!

Comment: Works on my machine. As already requested by others, please ask a real question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU parallel and awk):

```
parallel awk \''$2>{}'\' file '>' pos{}.pos ::: 5 10 15
```